# textChangedMethod for Multiple EditText boxes

Tags: java, android

Hi All  I have followed the following example http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=NumberFormattingTextWatcher&exact_package=android&type=cs

I have  CurrencyTextWatcher as a seperate class. I need this as I will be applying to several pages. 
I can't figure out why, but if I use **setContentView(text)** it will work as only 1 big text box, then I can't see the rest of my xml .
If I use **setContentView(R.layout.main);** my xml works properly except for the TextWatcher wont fire for my **txta EditText box**

Java

```
public class CalcTestActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText txta;
    private TextView txtb;
    private TextView txtc;
    private EditText text;

    private double a = 0;
    private double b = 0;
    private double c = 0;

    private Button buttonCalc;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            initControls();
            text = new EditText(this);
            text.addTextChangedListener(new CurrencyTextWatcher());
    //setContentView(text);
        }   

        private String FormatValue(double value)
        {
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
            return "$ "+ nf.format(value);
        }

        private void initControls() {

            txta = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txta);
            txtb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtb);
            txtc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtc);

            buttonCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCalc);
            buttonCalc.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {calculate(); }

            private void calculate() {

            a=Double.parseDouble(txta.getText().toString());

            b=Math.round(a*.88);                
            txtb.setText(FormatValue(b));

            c=Math.round((a*.87)-(b*.28));
            txtc.setText(FormatValue(c));
            }

        }); 
        }
    }
```

CurrencyTextWatcher Class

```
public class CurrencyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

boolean mEditing;

public CurrencyTextWatcher() {
    mEditing = false;
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!mEditing) {
        mEditing = true;

        String digits = s.toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        try{
            String formatted = nf.format(Double.parseDouble(digits)/100);
            s.replace(0, s.length(), formatted);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            s.clear();
        }

        mEditing = false;
    } 
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numeric="integer"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Answer is"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCalc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The code you have provided here is fine. But it would be still fine if u could elaborate more on your problem, its not clear

Comment: I am not sure how to get txta to use the currencytxtwatcher, if i put a content view text in it works but everything else is blocked out.

Comment: Updated the original Question so it was more clear on what i think is the issue.

Comment: Added the xml. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code. I observed that the code you have shared here is getting all views from xml.
In this case you are calling

```
 text.addTextChangedListener(new CurrencyTextWatcher());
```

in your onCreate method, wherein text is done using java. You wont get a call back for your onTextChanged, beforeTextChanged or afterTextChanged because all your views are taken from xml. So please after your

```
initControls();
```

in onCreate() add below line

```
 txta.addTextChangedListener(new CurrencyTextWatcher());
```

and comment

```
text.addTextChangedListener(new CurrencyTextWatcher());
```

that line is not needed. I have verified its working fine.

if works vote and accept the answer

Comment: Arun You are a Damn Star! Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me, I now understand what I was missing. I really appreciate it, and it works like a charm!Sorry I don't have high enough rep to vote up.

Answer (score 0):

what the code you have implemented in afterTextChanged implement the same for onTextChanged. It will fire and gives the call back.

Secondly, If there is problem in views check your layout and their params. if it is not proper it wont appear properly in the UI

Comment: I added the code in the ontext changed still doesn't work. I can't figure this out. Hard to Imagine, I can't find an example similar to what I am doing, it seems to be the contextview, but I can't find anything wrong in the xml. Like i said in question about the context.

Comment: Has anyone else ever done this? Have an idea what it might be?